# Which value is alpha in cv2 Laplacian function

Tags: python, opencv, laplacian

I am trying to apply Laplacian filter to image from following text.

```
cv.Laplacian(src, ddepth[, dst[, ksize[, scale[, delta[, borderType]]]]])
```

But I am not sure which value is alpha.

Text:

**we apply a 3×3 Laplacian filter with α = 0.2 to the image,** and take its absolute value to ignore the direction of the gradients. For color images, we apply the filter to each of the red, green, and blue channels separately and then take the mean across the channels. Finally, we resize Laplacian image size to 100 × 100 and normalize the image sum to 1. This allows us to easily calculate the edge spatial distribution of the professional photos and snapshots by taking the mean across all the Laplacian images in each set.

Comment: I believe it is refering to the MATLAB implementation https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/locallapfilt.html. They're two papers, `openCV` implementation is based on the 1st paper only.

Comment: Please provide a reference to how alpha is used in a Laplacian? Is this for edge detection or sharpening. In sharpening one would add alpha*laplacian to the original image.  Alpha would be scale in the Lapalacian arguments, but then you would have to add the laplacian result to the original image.

Comment: @fmw42 https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1640788/ here is the research. I can't see anything regarding which value is alpha. But as aminrd says Matlab function has include 2 parameters as alpha and beta.

Comment: @aminrd I see. Thank you! What about usage of sigma in function? There is no particular information about that in article.

Comment: please put that information in the question. it is vital for the understanding of this question. you can [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the use of an argument, possibly, alpha, for image sharpening is often done as follows:

```
result = input + alpha*Laplacian(input)
```

In terms of a convolution kernel that would be

```
result kernel = identify kernel + alpha * Laplacian kernel
```

So

```
result kernel = 0 0 0 + alpha *  0 -1  0
                0 1 0           -1  4 -1
                0 0 0            0 -1  0
```

and adding as

```
result kernel =    0    -alpha      0 
                -alpha 1+4*alpha -alpha
                   0    -alpha      0
```

The above may need clipping as it may overshoot.

So, alternately and probably better would be,

```
result = (1-alpha)*input + alpha*Laplacian(input)
```

So

```
result kernel = 0       0      0  +     0     -alpha      0
                0   (1-alpha)  0     -alpha   4*alpha  -alpha
                0       0      0        0     -alpha      0
```

and adding together as

```
result kernel =     0     -alpha      0
                 -alpha   1+3*alpha  -alpha
                    0     -alpha      0
```

So these would be implemented in Python/OpenCV as cv2.filter2D().

Note, that the negative of the Laplacian is typically used.

Comment: I am sorry for asking this but what would be simple implementation with cv2.filter2D() according to your notes?

Comment: Choose an alpha value (say 0.2) and then just put the last equation kernel values into filter2D(). See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga27c049795ce870216ddfb366086b5a04.

Comment: Alternately, use `(1-alpha)*input + alpha*Laplacian(input)` and simply do the blending using `cv2.addWeighted(image, (1-alpha), -cv2.Laplacian(image), alpha, 0)`